# Can I automate Microsoft Dynamics AX with Selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, axapta

Can I automate Microsoft Dynamics AX with Selenium webdriver ?

I have a task assigned to find a right framework to Automate the Microsoft Dynamics AX.

Can I use the Selenium webdriver for automation ?

Please Suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to automate? Testing? Enterprise Portal? AX forms in the AX client?

Comment: I have lesser idea about that ,Probably my question would end at if We can automate test the MS Dynamics AX with selenium webdriver. As I can see MS dynamics is more of a windows application.

Comment: From the description of [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org) you can probably use it to automate testing of the Enterprise Portal part of Dynamics AX. This might change with the next version of Dynamics AX, where the client is supposed to be entirely web browser based.

Answer (score 2):

With AX 7, Selenium will be a great tool for testing the AX application because the client will be webbased. (FH-Inway already pointed that out in a comment above).

I'm just following up on this now, because I saw the question now and AX 7 is to be released soon. I have some experience with Selenium and I'm happy that we will be able to use Selenium with AX 7.

Answer (score 1):

No, for AX 2012 and below.  As FH-Inway pointed out Selenium Webdriver is for automated testing of web applications, such as the [AX Enterprise Portal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa855178.aspx).

Have you tried [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), or writing an [AX Batch Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa882882.aspx) to directly do the work!...  The second option requires a [developers licence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh456310.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using ui-automation to automated desktop applications.

ui-automation is a framework for automating (via the MS UIAutomation library) rich client applications based on Win32 (including Delphi), WPF and other Windows applications ((including Java SWT)). It is written in Java, using the JNA library to make calls to the COM-based WIndows automation library.

You can find more details [here](https://github.com/mmarquee/ui-automation).